# Перетаскивание файлов Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rider

Не могу перетащить файл из окна Solution Explorer в любую папку, например, на рабочий стол. Must have фича, ранее пользовался продуктом от JetBrains - Rider.

Comment: Это замечание нужно разрабам VS отправить, а не сюда. В верхнем правом углу VS есть иконка чела с пузырём кликайте туда и пишите ваши желания по Must have фичам.

Comment: @Bulson надеялся, что есть что-нибудь на подобии дополнения. Очень жаль, спасибо за ответ